# How can I determine state based on whether or not it's coming from a route param or a mutation?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I need to get a record in multiple places outside of my record component and am using Vuex and a mounted call tho get the record:

**Vuex**

```js
state: {
    record: null,
    loaded: false,
    currentRecordId: null
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_CURRENT_RECORD_ID(state, recordId){
      state.currentRecordId = recordId
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getRecord(context){
        axios.get('api/thought'+this.state.currentRecordId)
          .then(response => {
            context.commit('SET_RECORD_DATA', response.data.data)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            
          })
    }
},
```

**Record Component**

```js
mounted() {
    this.getRecord()
},

methods: {
    getRecord: function(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getRecord');
    },
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the `currentRecordId` state will need to come from a route parameter `this.$route.params.hashedId` and sometimes it will be set by the `SET_CURRENT_RECORD_ID()` mutation. The reason being is the record needs to be gotten from various modals and other components. For example:

**Records Component**

```html
<template>
<div v-for="record in records">
    <button><span @click="setRecordHashedId(record.id)" class='bg-blue'> <v-icon class="mr-1">launch</v-icon> View/add details</span></button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
           return {
                records: null,
           }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getRecords()
        },
        methods: {
            setRecordHashedId(hashedId) {
                this.$store.commit('SET_CURRENT_RECORD_ID', hashedId);
                this.$router.push({ name: 'record', params: {hashedId: hashedId } })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So how do I determine in Vuex if the `currentRecordId` is coming from a route param or a mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a payload parameter in your action for the ID, falling back to the one in your state if it's not set?

```js
actions: {
  getRecord: async ({ commit, state }, recordId) => {
    const url = `api/thought${encodeURIComponent(recordId ?? state.currentRecordId)}`
    const { data: { data } } = await axios.get(url)
    commit('SET_RECORD_DATA', data)
  }
}
```

Then you can dispatch either way

```js
this.$store.dispatch("getRecord") // use state.currentRecordId
// or
this.$store.dispatch("getRecord", this.$route.params.hashedId)
```

---

If your environment doesn't support the [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`), try this legacy option

```js
recordId = typeof recordId !== "undefined" ? recordId : state.currentRecordId
const url = `api/thought${encodeURIComponent(recordId)}`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the best way to go about it, but for some reason I'm getting an Expression `expected error ":"` in VScode. Sorry I'm new to `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @KyleCorbinHurst on which line?

Comment: `const url = `api/thought${encodeURIComponent(recordId ?? state.currentRecordId)}``

Comment: Hmm, might be the [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). As a test, try `const url = \`api/thought${encodeURIComponent(recordId || state.currentRecordId)}\``. I'm surprised VSCode shows a warning for that. Perhaps it needs an update or your ES level is set too low